# Can I access a C# enum in my Razor view?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I have the following:

```
namespace Storage.Constants.References {
    public enum RoleType {
        Guest = 1,
        User = 2,
        Admin = 3,
        Super = 4
    }
}
```

In my web.config I added:

```
<add namespace="Storage.Constants.References" />
```

However in my view below I still don't get any intellisense for the RoleType and it appears to not know what it is:

```
@model WebUx.ViewModels.BaseViewModel
@{ Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml"; }
@section status {

    @if (Model.Role >= RoleType.Admin)
    {
```

However it works if I change this to:

```
@if (Model.Role >= Storage.Constants.References.RoleType.Admin)
```

Should it not work without my specifying "Storage.Constants.References" ?

Comment: Did you add it to the web.config closest to the view, not your main web.config?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Did you try adding the namspace to your razor view ?

```
@using Storage.Constants.References
```

Also, if you are adding it in the web config file, make sure you are adding to the webconfig present in the **Views** folder, not the root level web config

Comment: I just tried that now and it works. However any idea why adding to the web-config that's in the parent folder will not work?

Comment: try to add to ~/Views/web.config.

Comment: I am using Areas and it's already in:
/Areas/Admin/Content/Views/Web.config
Would it ignore the file when there. It seems a good location for the web.config

Comment: if you work with areas, you need to put it in the web.config under Views folder under your Area

Comment: That's where I put it but it didn't seem to use it :-(

Answer (score 0):

In Blazor WebAssembly razor page, put @using namespac

```
@using Yoyo.Shared.Enum
```

Use your enum in razor page

```
@if (participant.State == TestState.Started.ToString())
{ }
```

In C#, your enum in namespace Yoyo.Shared.Enum

```
namespace Yoyo.Shared.Enum
{
    public enum TestState
    {
        NotStarted = 0,
        Started = 1
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The answeres are not all correct for static enums:

do:

```
@using static XXX.Data.Helpers.Enums; // ur class where ur enums are
```

and then:

```
 value="@YourEnum.YourValue"
```